# Why can't I set the PDF minor version after loading beamer class?

Tags: beamer, pdftex

My issue is, that I have a theme that loads PDFs that are PDF version 1.7. Therefore I want my theme to set the minor version to 7. While it is possible to set the minor version after selecting the document class with e.g. `article`, `beamer` seems to do something in the class, so we can't, every call after `\documentclass` to change the PDF version leads to: `pdfTeX error (setup): \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file. \begin{document}`

An MWE to do it in a theme would be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{mytheme} %Remove the comment after a successful run, otherwise file will not be created
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{beamerthememytheme.sty}
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=7
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Just a slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A workaround is to set `\pdfinclusionerrorlevel=-1`, but I don't like that, because it creates PDFs that look like a lower version, than they actually contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

beamer creates some objects when loading the class (it declares images in the default inner theme), and so the pdf version can not be changed later.

Sadly this here doesn't work either.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfversion=1.7}]{beamer}
```

At the time hyperref is loaded the version still could be set, but hyperref is too careful, it detects that pgf has reserved a few objects and then refuses to set the version.

The only thing that works is to change before loading the class:

```
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=7
\documentclass{beamer}
```

If other engines should be used the expl3 command can be used, it works for alle engines:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_ensure_backend: %forces loading of backend, in older systems use \RequirePackage{expl3}
\pdf_version_gset:n{1.7}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Comment: So this solution does not work if LuaTeX is used, right?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas I added an edit for an engine independant version.